# Can GAE be configured to launch a new instance per request?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm building a data processing application, where I want an incoming (REST) request to cause a cloud instance to be started, do some processing, then retrieve the results. Typically, it would be something like this:

1. receive request
2. start instance
3. send request to instance
4. instance processes (~100% load on all instance CPUs)
5. poll service running on instance for status
6. fetch results from instance
7. shut down instance

I was planning on doing the instance management manually using something like jclouds, but am wondering if GAE could be configured to do something like this (saving me work).

If I have my processing service set up in GAE, can I make it so that a new instance is launched for every incoming request (or whenever the current instance(s) are at 100% CPU usage)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to instance management only (i.e. 1-4 and 7)...

From [Scaling dynamic instances](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-instances-are-managed#scaling_dynamic_instances):

> The App Engine scheduler decides whether to serve each new request
>   with an existing instance (either one that is idle or accepts
>   concurrent requests), put the request in a pending request queue, or
>   start a new instance for that request. The decision takes into account
>   the number of available instances, how quickly your application has
>   been serving requests (its latency), and how long it takes to spin up
>   a new instance.
>
> Each instance has its own queue for incoming requests. App Engine
>   monitors the number of requests waiting in each instance's queue. If
>   App Engine detects that queues for an application are getting too long
>   due to increased load, it automatically creates a new instance of the
>   application to handle that load.
>
> App Engine also scales instances in reverse when request volumes
>   decrease. This scaling helps ensure that all of your application's
>   current instances are being used to optimal efficiency and cost
>   effectiveness.

So in the [scaling configuration](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#scaling_elements) I'd keep [`automatic_scaling`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appref#automatic_scaling) (which is the default) and play with:

- [`max_pending_latency`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appref#max_pending_latency):

> The maximum amount of time that App Engine should allow a request
>   to wait in the pending queue before starting a new instance to handle
>   it. The default value is "30ms".
>
> - A low maximum means App Engine will start new instances sooner for pending requests, improving performance but raising running costs.
> - A high maximum means users might wait longer for their requests to be served (if there are pending requests and no idle instances to
>     serve them), but your application will cost less to run.

- [`min_pending_latency`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appref#min_pending_latency):

> The minimum amount of time that App Engine should allow a request to
>   wait in the pending queue before starting a new instance to handle it.
>
> - A low minimum means requests must spend less time in the pending queue when all existing instances are active. This improves
>     performance but increases the cost of running your application.
> - A high minimum means requests will remain pending longer if all existing instances are active. This lowers running costs but increases
>     the time users must wait for their requests to be served.

See also in [Change auto scaling performance settings](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/console/managing-resources#change_auto_scaling_performance_settings):

> - **Min Pending Latency** - Raising [Min Pending Latency](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appref#automatic_scaling) instructs App Engine’s scheduler to not start a new instance unless a request
>     has been pending for more than the specified time. If all instances
>     are busy, user-facing requests may have to wait in the pending queue
>     until this threshold is reached. Setting a high value for this setting
>     will require fewer instances to be started, but may result in high
>     user-visible latency during increased load.

You may also want to take a look at [Warmup requests](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-instances-are-managed#warmup_requests), in case you want to reduce the latency for requests which would cause a new instance to be started.